# PowerShell Advanced Function -parameter Binding

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-Uptime
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
   
    Param
    (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Alias("ComputerName","Name")] 
        [string[]]
        $ServerName
      )

    Begin
    {
      Write-Verbose "Begin Processing"  
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach($server in $ServerName)
        {
            Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server|select @{n="ServerName";e={$_.PSComputerName}},LastBootUpTime,@{n="Uptime";E={$(((get-date)-$_.LastBootUpTime)|select @{N="time";e={"$($_.days) Days $($_.Hours) Hours $($_.Minutes) Minutes "}}).time}}
        }    
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "End Processing"
    }
}
```

Below function call is Working

```
"localhost","winser2012-001"|Get-Uptime 
Get-Uptime -ServerName "localhost","winser2012-001"

Get-ADComputer -filter *|select name|Get-Uptime
```

why function call without **Select name** is Not working please help on this

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * |Get-Uptime
```

Comment: It seems PS is trying to work out what parameter(s) to map, but it's got a lot of options to try (does it take the object from the pipeline, a property with the given name, a property with one of the aliases, should it just take the input properties that match (what about the remaining properties), do the property types match or can the input be converted to match the required type, etc).   You can see what's going on by running ` Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { <# YOUR CODE HERE #> } -PSHost`...

Comment: I don't know the exact rules; but playing with a simplified example and a few different approaches it seems that in your specific case PowerShell's just decided that the combination required to get the input object to match the parameters is too convoluted for it to proceed.  Whether that's a bug or by design, I'm not sure.  There's some more info here - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/two-ways-to-accept-pipeline-input-in-powershell/ba-p/258883 - though sadly the chart they've included doesn't show the case for parameters accepting both ByValue and Name.

Comment: 2 things I'm seeing.  1) It works fine in PS 7.1.4  2) In PS 5.1 it's works only if the parameter name is changed to '$Name'.  It doesn't seem to want to work for aliases.  Quick google search has turned up other reports of the issue with AD objects https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1065228-parameter-binding-by-alias

Comment: Can you be more descriptive than "Not working"? Do you get an error? If so, what does the error message say? If not, then what behavior _are_ you observing?

Comment: I am getting this error message , when call the function like this 

Get-ADComputer -filter *|Get-Uptime

 " Get-Uptime : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ServerName'. The argument 
is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the 
command again.
At line:1 char:26
+ Get-ADComputer -filter *|Get-Uptime + CategoryInfo  : InvalidData: (CN=WINSER2012-0...wintricks,DC=in:   PSObject) [Get-Uptime], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Get-Uptime "
Get-ADComputer -filter *|select name|Get-Uptime is working

Comment: I am trying to match the Name property (holding server names) from Get-ADcomputer -filter* with Get-uptime function parameter $serverName through alias Name (ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName), I except that it will take the Name property of Get-ADcomputer -filter* to match with alias Name. Thanks Daniel its working after changing the actual parameter $ServerName to $Name. however I want match with alias name. I am completely new to advanced function . please help on this

Comment: Check that link in my comment.  There seems to be a bug in using ByPropertyName by alias when piping AD objects.  If you are fine with using PS 7 instead of 5.1 your original solution will work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members

There seems to be a bug in using `ByPropertyName` by an `alias` when piping AD objects. If you are fine with using `PS 7` instead of `PS 5.1`, it works as expected.

You can refer to [Parameter Binding by Alias](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1065228-parameter-binding-by-alias)